# IAM users can't see Athena tables

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-athena

My IAM users can't see the Athena tables I've created a long time ago using the root account.

Their group has the following permissions:

- AmazonS3FullAccess
- AmazonAthenaFullAccess

They only see the `sampledb` databases, which is unfortunate, because they need the one we actually use. The documentation is not clear on how to make the databases accessible to everyone. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Do they see any other values in the DATABASE drop-down list? Are you sure they are looking in the correct region?

Answer (score 4):

Your permissions are correct.

Athena's context is not currently shared across regions. Ensure that the users are viewing Athena from the same region as the root account. When they login to AWS, they may be initially placed in another region.

Answer (score 0):

You need Glue permissions, Glue is the service in charge of manage Databases and Tables in AWS